# How to make a turning 3D box not look like top is floating?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple 3D box using only html and css which shows one side (and the top) normally and then spins to show another side when the mouse is over it. I've managed most of it but it still looks a bit funky and I have no idea how to make it actually look good. The biggest problem seems to be poor placement of the top and some discreet bobbing on the sides while turning. I don't really know how to solve it, not in a proper way at least.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.side1,
.side2,
.side3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  perspective: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.side1 {
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f88;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}

.side2 {
  background-color: #f00;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: translateX(0) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

.side3 {
  background-color: #500;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: translateX(50px) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(-90deg);
}

div:hover>.side1 {
  transform: rotateX(-60deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

div:hover>.side2 {
  background-color: #f88;
  transform: translateX(-50px) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(90deg);
}

div:hover>.side3 {
  background-color: #f00;
  transform: translate(0) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="side1"></div>
  <div class="side2"></div>
  <div class="side3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might find this helpful https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/cube

Comment: @j08691 A lot, actually. It solved the entire thing!